# SQL update with joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I have data *table1.fieldToChange* that is currently populated from *table2.oldData*... but I would like to update this and change it to *table2.newData*

Here's the code I am using to try and achieve this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.fieldToChange =
  (SELECT table2.newData
  FROM table2
  WHERE table2.oldData = table1.newData
  ) ;
```

But I get an 'ORA-01427' error.

Both *table2.newData* and *table2.oldData* are unique identifiers and only used once in the database. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [ORA-01427](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01427.php) indicates you are returning more than one value in a subquery. Modify your query to contain a DISTINCT clause or some other mechanism to uniquely identify a row in the subquery.

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.fieldToChange =
  (SELECT DISTINCT table2.newData
  FROM table2
  WHERE table2.oldData = table1.newData
  ) ;
```

Comment: unless you are working with a primary key, you would also need to add TOP 1 to be absolutely safe

Comment: Many thanks both, but unfortunately it just returns the same result regardless of what table1.fieldToChange was set to

Comment: Any chance your query, or at least your psuedocode provided is incorrect? I find it's helpful when writing update statements to write them as SELECTs first to ensure I am getting the expected results (comment out the Update line and make SET into SELECT).

Answer (score 1):

try it with [MERGE statement](http://www.sc.ehu.es/siwebso/KZCC/Oracle_10g_Documentacion/server.101/b10759/statements_9016.htm):

```
MERGE INTO table1 tgt
USING (SELECT newData,oldData 
         FROM table2
        WHERE table2.oldData = table1.newData) src
ON (src.oldData = tgt.newData)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.fieldToChange = src.newData;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an invalid identifier error that I can't seem to squash :/

Comment: it could be helpful if you write us the actual sql you are using

Comment: MERGE INTO "Employee" a
USING (SELECT "Location_Code", "Location_Add1"
         FROM "Location"
        WHERE "Location"."Location_Add1" = "Employee"."Location_Code") b
ON (b."Location_Add1" = a."Gp_Nearest_Station")
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET a."Gp_Nearest_Station" = b."Location_Code";

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean?

```
UPDATE table1
SET fieldToChange =
  (SELECT table2.newData
  FROM table2
  WHERE table2.oldData = table1.fieldToChange     ---- and NOT table1.newData ?
  ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works in Oracle, but in MS SQL you can do this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET fieldToChange = table2.newData
FROM table2  
WHERE table2.oldData = fieldToChange
```

Note that you cannot have an alias on the table being updated.

Comment: Thanks, just tried this but get a 'command not properly ended' message :(